MongoDB and Ops Manager installation on docker image
I'm trying to install MongoDB Ops Manager on docker image for testing.
I can't find a clear steps to do that, I tried many times without any result.
I installed MongoDB engine and it's working fine, but the issue in Ops Manager, I don't know if there i can link the ops manager with MongoDB community edition or not , also I don't know if i can install ops manager on docker image.
Also, what is the suitable for doing this if this is doable Ubuntu or redhat ?
I used these steps to install MonogDB engine
Install MongoDB Steps:
1- apt update
2- sudo apt-get install gnupg curl
3- apt install gnupg
4- curl -fsSL https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-7.0.asc | 
sudo gpg -o /usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-7.0.gpg 
--dearmor
5- echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-7.0.gpg ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/7.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-7.0.list
6- sudo apt-get update
7- sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
8- apt install systemctl
9- sudo systemctl status mongod
10- mongosh
and everything is working fine until now,
then tried to install ops manager using the steps mentioned in this link https://www.mongodb.com/docs/ops-manager/v5.0/tutorial/install-simple-test-deployment/ (steps for install ops manager only)
Also tried another random steps found on the internet but without any result.
Anyone has a clear recommendation ? and keep in mind i'm trying with MongoDB community edition and Ops Manager for Enterprise edition because there is no Ops Manager for community edit.
